# Segmented Tab Layout with RecyclerView Data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to make a custom view with two Recyclerview data. First one is header titles, second one is content details. When I click on a title, I want different XML files to be shown.

After some research, I saw that I could do it using TabLayout and ViewPager, however, I don't want to use an extra fragment for each tab, instead I want to inflate an XML file. Because I want to use this view on other screens as a custom view.

[image]

How can I do that? What should I use as a solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewPager2 :

```
 <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/topicViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />
```

you can assign second recycler adapter to ViewPager2 for example:-

```
class DummyAdapter(var list:ArrayList<String>) : 
RecyclerView.Adapter<DummyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
lateinit var context: Context
var isFullScreen = false
var isDownload: Boolean = false
var doubleClick = false

inner class ViewHolder(val binding: DummyItemBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(
        position: Int,
        context: Context,
        adapter: DummyAdapter,
    ) {
        with(binding) {
         // add data

        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
ViewHolder {
    context = parent.context
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    val binding = DummyItemBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) =
    holder.bind(position, context, this, list[position])


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}
```

}

```
binding.viewPager.adapter = dummyAdapter
```

then on the click of TabLayout you can update the adapter of second recyclerView.